# Web Site Administration Tool in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I can't figure out how to configure my web.config in order to make the web-site-admistration tool work with an MVC 4 project in visual studio 2012.

Here are the steps to reproduce this behaviour

- create a new MVC4 project in visual studio 2012
- run the project (ctrl+f5)
- register yourself and login. You will notice that in the app_data folder, a new file is created. e.g. aspnet-MvcApplication6-20121009211525.mdf
- if you open the mdf file (within visual studio), you will be able to browse the schema in the server explorer window.
- now start the web site administration tool (project->asp.net configuration). Try to go to the security tab. You should see me message like this:

> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused
>   by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient
>   permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not
>   being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where
>   you can choose a new data store. 
>   The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to
>   connect to SQL Server database.

I already googled for a solution to my problem but it seems that most answers are targeting older versions of MVC / visual studio, so I wasn't successful yet. What surprises me is there is no membership nor a roleManager section in the web.config when you use the standard MVC 4 template (whereas if you create a ASP.NET Forms application you'll see both sections. Unfortunately I got the same error with the ASP.NET WebForms template so I didn't continue to investigate.). Also, the roleManager or membership config sections typically define a provider which is comes from the System.Web.Provider assembly. The MVC 4 template does not even reference the System.Web.Provider assembly, so I wonder how the role/membership works in MVC 4. It might be obsolete in the new version but I didn't find information on this topic (the System.Web.Security assembly seems to replace System.Web.Provider). My error might also be related to the fact that I only have LocalDB installed and no other SQL server instance.

So my question is: Can you reproduce this error and are you able to fix it? What is the cause of this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I developed a replacement to the Website Administration Tool for MVC found here: http://aaron-hoffman.blogspot.com/2013/08/aspnet-mvc-4-simplemembershipprovider_20.html code: https://github.com/StoneFinch/SmpMaintenance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the answer here: [The ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool (WSAT) is not compatible with SimpleMembership](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)

Comment: Any custom solutions to address this functionality ? Or we have to develop our own solution. i.e make crud for users and role and assign roles to users, have listing of users and roles and roles having permissions to view/modify pages of website.